# Linux box with only one application which is fullscreen

Tags: linux, desktop

Sorry for the rather broad question, but I'm just looking for some leads here to get started on this...

Let's say I have a CentOS machine running the X Windows System.  I'd like to have the machine only display a single application (let's say Mozilla Firefox) and have that application full screen at all times.  Is there a more suitable distro to do this with than CentOS?

I hope I've given enough information here about what I want to do.

Thanks!

Comment: yeah, it's random. But look at other sites: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129367/dedicated-purpose-single-application-linux-boxes :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are looking for kiosk mode, you can achieve this by various kiosk based linux based iso distribution like http://sanickiosk.wikidot.com/ (Sanickiosk) and WebKiosk 
(http://www.binaryemotions.com/).

Even you can customize ubuntu to run only firefox in full screen mode (http://www.instructables.com/id/Setting-Up-Ubuntu-as-a-Kiosk-Web-Appliance/?ALLSTEPS).

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker

Comment: "kiosk" was exactly the keyword I was looking for - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm really not sure if this is the proper place, but the disto for this type of use hardly matters, its really up to personal preference and how hard you find it to set up.  In my limited expirence you can just add the command to launch the app, typically with a geometry option (with firefox you can specify the -width and -height flags), and then that X session will end when the program ends.